# JAWS repeating description when pressing keys to type

Tags: javascript, html, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I'm trying to fix an issue with JAWS 2023, when I hit some key in these textboxes it announces like this:
if I type "P" on the textbox, it's announced as "P username P" or "P password P". Have no idea what may be causing this, only happens in a few fields.

```
<input id="textboxUsername" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="on" type="text" placeholder="Username" maxlength="30" tabindex="0" role="textbox" aria-level="1">

<input id="textboxPassword" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="on" type="text" placeholder="Password" maxlength="30"tabindex="0" role="textbox" aria-level="1">
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question I'm afraid (I've never used JAWS and it isn't free!), but I can't help noticing that you are using `aria-level` on `input` elements, which is completely meaningless and not even allowed in the specification. (This attribute is only used on headings and a few other roles - none of them interactive ones.) Also the `tabindex="0"` and `role="textbox"` are superfluous.

Comment: I agree that `tabindex` and `role` are not needed (see https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#el-input-text) but it doesn't hurt anything. And also agree that `aria-level` is misused (see "Used in Roles" in https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-level). I have JAWS 2020 and I don't hear the issue when using your code snippet. What do you have your "typing echo" JAWS setting set to? Characters, Words, or both? I'm not sure that would affect what you're hearing but worth changing the setting to see if you hear something different. The `placeholder` should not be announced after you start typing.